# Pushing to git Windows share from shell script

Tags: windows, bash, git, batch-file

I'm trying to push my local repository using a batch or shell script on Windows 10 to a remote Windows share.

This is the command I use in Powershell/Bash/Git-Bash (on Windows):

```
git push --mirror file://[RemoteDriveLetter]:PersonalFolder/MyRepository
```

I use the mirror command because it's simply the case of performing a remote backup in case my hard drive were to ever fail. This command works perfectly fine if I run the command myself.

However, I'm trying to get this automated so it will copy every night without me having to do anything. Therefore, I created the batch file below (**push.bat**):

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "c/repo/sync.sh"
```

The contents of **sync.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash/
cd /c/repo/
git push --mirror file://[RemoteDriveLetter]:PersonalFolder/MyRepository
```

The combination of running the scheduled .bat file, which then launches the bash shell. When running this batch file, I get the following output:

> fatal: '[RemoteDriveLetter]:PersonalFolder/MyRepository' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Any ideas why, when I run the same exact command(s) in git-bash/powershell/bash that it pushes my repository correctly and in a batch file/shell script that it bails at the push?

Things I've tried and haven't worked:

- Encapsulating the path in single (') and double (") quotes.
- Running both the batch file and shell script as administrator
- Altering the shell script by setting the origin url instead:

  ```
  git remote set-url origin file://[RemoteDriveLetter]:PersonalFolder/MyRepository
  git push --mirror -u origin (and without the -u)
  ```
- Converting it all to a powershell script

I'm currently at a loss, help please!

Comment: And if you use the path format: `[RemoteDriveLetter]:/PersonalFolder/MyRepository`? Don't use `file://` that is not supported.

Comment: I've also tried `file://[RemoteDriveLetter]:/PersonalFolder/MyRepository` and it does not work.I'll take a look trying to remove `file://` as well. Someone told me long ago that's how you access git using a network share, so I'll check it out.

Comment: Did you initialise the remote as a `bare` repository? http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/ https://githowto.com/bare_repositories

Comment: I tried removing the `file://` portion, but that still results in the same issue: `[RemoteDriveLetter]:/PersonalFolder/MyRepository does not appear to be a git repository`.

@TimothyTruckle - The repository has indeed been initialized as a bare repository. Like I said, I can push and pull fine using the git-bash interactively myself, but when run from the batch file it does not work. Just to make sure, I created a new bare repository at `U:/PersonalFolder/TestRepository` and it still results in the same error messages I have been seeing.